# How to access variable from parent module in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

If I have this TypeScript code:

```
module Foo
{
    var x : string ="value";
    module Bar
    {
        export var x = x;
    }
}
```

It compiles to the following JavaScript:

```
var Foo;
(function (Foo) {
    var x = "value";
    var Bar;
    (function (Bar) {
        Bar.x = Bar.x;
    })(Bar || (Bar = {}));

})(Foo || (Foo = {}));
```

The problem is the line that says `Bar.x = Bar.x`. How can I set Bar.x to Foo.x? Is it required to `export` `Foo.x` so I can say `Bar.x = Foo.x`?

Comment: it looks like a shadowing issue. `export var _x = x` works fine.

Comment: Yes - in plain JavaScript `var x = x;` won't fetch the value of the parent `x` because of the semantics of `var` statements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is definitely possible if you remove the ambiguity in the naming:

```
module Foo
{
    var a : string = "My Value";
    export module Bar
    {
        export var x = a;
    }
}

alert(Foo.Bar.x);
```

Comment: I was hoping something like Foo.x or parent.x would work without an export. I have quite a lot of variables I would have to rename

Comment: I can't think of a way that doesn't involve exporting `a` and prefixing it with `Foo` on the inner module or renaming to `x` on the inner module.